# ejs templating engine data rendering error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></span>
  <%
 <input id="vvcode" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="requestId" 
value="
<%= 
requestId %>" required/> 
%>
</div>
</div>
```

i'm getting a "Could not find matching close tag for \"<%\"." error. please help, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite specific.

You have an opening control flow `<%` but then you mix some html without closing it with `%>`

You should either do something inside like:

```
<% if (something) { %>
Html content
<% } %>
```

Or just remove them:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></span>
        <input id="vvcode" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="requestId" value="<%= requestId %>" required/> 
    </div>
</div>
```